# How to display time on a JavaFX line chart ??? Category Axis does not work for large data

Tags: java, javafx

I have a JavaFX line chart where I want to display the x axis as time/string value.

I tried using a Category axis which converts my time in milliseconds values into string. But if I have a large group of data for the chart the chart gets unresponsive and it it trying to draw a ton of categories on the axis for every time value.  So I need something that is smart enough to display time correctly

Comment: Code is worth 1000 words

Comment: A `NumberAxis` with a [`tickLabelFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/chart/ValueAxis.html#tickLabelFormatterProperty) set? Hard to know if that would work from your question...

Comment: how do I set up a tickLabelFormatter to convert the Number into a time string

Comment: I just figured out how to add the tick label formatter